# Production/staging auto install new docker image from registry.gitlab.com in a gitlab-ci job

Tags: gitlab-ci

I created a GitLab CI pipeline with these steps :

1. lint
2. test
3. build (create docker package, register it in register.gitlab.com)

From there I would like to add a 4th step which would be to trigger my Docker server to pull that new docker image and install it (when merge is done in master of course).

I am wondering if there's a standard way to do this instead of sshing and stuff in the gitlab-ci.yml script.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**.gitlab-ci.yml** fragment could look like this:

```yaml
...
step 3 - build and deploy:
  script:
    - docker build -t "${IMAGE_TAG}" .
    - docker login registry.example.com -u <username> -p <token>
    - docker push ${IMAGE_TAG}

step 4 - pull and validate:
  script:
    - docker login registry.example.com -u <username> -p <token>
    - docker pull ${IMAGE_TAG}
    - <test your pulled docker image however you want>
```

I don't understand what are you ssh'ing. You could generate token and just login to gitlab registry.
More info in [docs](https://gitlab.com/help/user/packages/container_registry/index)